# Permission / attribute based authorization in loopback js

Tags: node.js, authorization, loopbackjs, abac

In LoopbackJS, authorization is built to depend on roles for authorization like: if user is in role x then he is allowed/denied to access method y.

I'm looking to build a system with more flexible authorization management module that allows creating new roles and assigning permissions to those roles, then adding users to them. Hence, authorization should be permission-based instead of role-based. Like: if user has any role with permission x then he is allowed to access method y.

I tried to look for any online resources that allow deeper mapping to permissions for authorization instead of roles but failed to find any. I can try to twist the use of [role resolver](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#role-registerresolver) to do this job, but I feel that there should be something I missed which should be easier to implement with such a rich framework like loopbackJS.

Comment: Look into attribute based access control (abac) e.g. XACML, Axiomatics, or Open Policy Agent

Comment: Any luck with this? Need the same thing, and wouldn't want to re-write this manually. This is the reason we are migrating from SailsJS to Loopback...

Comment: @VladyslavatAssuredLabs, what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @AlBaraaSh I basically need the REST endpoints to be fully secured by a kind of built-in, or imported library. From looking at loopback docs, what I see is.. disabling all default actions line by line when those are not allowed - that doesn't sound right.

Comment: @AlBaraaSh we want to simply define role permissions in a file, and based on user roles contained - grant only specified REST endpoints. The REST would be the auto-generated one